# Which system settings should I put to create a virtual machine in Oracle VM?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

I am a computer science student and I have been suffering problems to create a virtual machine in my laptop. To put you in context I have a laptop with an AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics 1.80 GHz and a 16GB RAM. I am using VirtualBox 6.1.32.

I have tried searching in internet but with the settings that I found it doesn't work, sometimes when I try to install it goes all dark and stays like that or if I am able to install (only once) it works VERY slowly (with 10024 base memory and 8 processors) and I don't know what to do. I have been thinking of changing of computer and buy another one too because I'm desperate to find a solution because I will need it to study very soon.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider editing your question to include more information about the settings you've tried, and what exact steps you took to figure out what was going on during the time you describe the VM as being very slow. The more relevant information you provide the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.